# Can I use email addresses as usernames in django-auth?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'd like to use email addresses as a pseudo-username of sorts while using Django's auth module. Can I do this? `User.username` is limited to 30 characters which really isn't acceptable for longer email addresses. I know that the `User` object also has an `email_address` property, but I'm not sure that this is for authentication. The problem is that `username` is *required*, but is too short for my application to be usable. For my application, a pseudonym such as a username doesn't make any sense, so I don't know how I can make this work. Is there a way to do what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the `username` programatically and subclass the auth backend to support emails:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CustomAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None, username=None,
                     *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        # fallback to login + password
        return super(CustomAuthBackend, self).authenticate(username=username,
                                                           password=password,
                                                           *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you give a good example of how to generate a good random username which won't collide with any other ones in the database?

Comment: `''.join([random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') for i in range(0,30)])`

Comment: Note that you'll need to `import random` to do that, obviously.

Comment: You could also set the username to `'user%s' % (self.pk, )`.

Keep in mind that Django does not enforce the uniqueness of email addresses so you will need to do that in your registration forms.